# The many ways to skin a `cat`

Tags: code-challenge, popularity-contest, bash

The well known `cat` command simply copies its stdin directly to stdout unchanged. But there are plenty of other commandline tools that exist...

What other commands can be used to duplicate the functionality of the venerable `cat`?

## Rules

1. You are not allowed to use any *shell* features, including pipes, file redirection, variables, etc.
2. Your answer can only *directly* invoke one command - e.g. `foo-cmd; bar` is disallowed because you are directly invoking both `foo-cmd` and `bar` (not to mention, the use of a semicolon breaks rule 1). However, commands that internally execute other commands (such as `xargs`) **are** allowed.
3. The command you use should already exist and be at least somewhat widely known. And an explanation of nontrivial answers would also be nice.
4. This contest is not about finding a single "best" cat implementation, and as such will not have a single accepted answer. Rather, this is an exercise in creativity: how many different ways can we collectively implement `cat`?

## Solutions

So far, we have a `cat` implementation for the following commands (add yours to the list when you answer):

- [`awk`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269635/112209)
- [`sed`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269637/111474)

Comment: @Seggan Not OP, but for me, no: (a) this is a popularity contest, and (b) this is assumingly only for bash. I'll request adding a bash tag.

Comment: @Joao-3 but all these answers are just as valid answers for the other question. also popularity contests are very much frowned upon

Comment: @Seggan Different people have different opinions

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/sed)

```
sed ""
```

Plain old sed with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

## [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)

```
awk '1{print}'
```

Explanation:

- `1` -> match every line.
- `{print}` -> for each matched line, print it

Or, more tersely:

```
awk 1
```

Here, a missing block implies `{print}`.